# how to join two tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'am stuck in an sql query and I didn't know how to do it,
well, first, I Have two tables

```
Comments :
id INT A.I
date_created  INT
update_id INT
comment TEXT

and Another Table

users
id
username
firstname
lastname
```

I Managed to display the comment and the date because it's in the same table, but I wanna join the username with the comment, and I tried to do the query with Navicat but I did not worked, 
Please if anyone have an idea, just comment it , 
and thank you

Comment: your table miss a foreigner key : you need the id of the user in the comment table

Comment: You need to know how those tables are related, the *Foreign Key* definitions? When the `update_id` contains user ids it's a `from comments as c join users as u on c.update_id = u.id`

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose you have two tables like :

**Users**

```
UserID | INT
Name   | VARCHAR(250)
EMail  | VARCHAR(250)
```

**Comments**

```
CommentsID | INT 
UserID     | INT
Comments   | VARCHAR(MAX)
```

The join will be like the following

```
SELECT * FROM Comments c INNER JOIN users u ON c.UserID=u.UserID
```

In Your case query will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM Comments c INNER JOIN users u ON c.update_id =u.id
```

Comment: @Firas Jerbi try this

Answer (score 0):

Query For you

```
SELECT * 
FROM Comments T1 
INNER JOIN users T2 
ON T1.update_id = T2.id
```

**SQL INNER JOIN**

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in
>   both tables.

**INNER JOIN Syntax**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

To Learn more about join [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)